# Linkedin API update troubling with authentication scheme with share api

Tags: php, api, share, linkedin-api

Can anyone please explain how to use the share api of linkedin after the changes been updated as per my understanding I have updated the code and i am getting the below response. I tried using the share.php from https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn

```
{"access_token":"AQXklP-2r5D1JQf5m_PfOMQoDcT6MCjaTHhAhaMDAbPP3CtB4aWsWPdEr4xt9jtDsABykDHixcqyCdjPdpuqdcpIUTql_DG6MHXaTfdAK9P_8cpItmLI6y2T7hBT-bBv0g-z-0TvUivFjrAvN-m_L1iXz_O7PnJcE60Gd00G3_VTY-ex4Bs","expires_in":5173195}{ "errorCode": 0, "message": "Unknown authentication scheme", "requestId": "5NWY2NR7YZ", "status": 401, "timestamp": 1436186085958 }1


{"access_token":"AQXLJf6S8KuOqqnXTx4Ujt0lJuAX7ETe2nrPirdnjDhl8RrPqem9dFbxZZa-EV91_rfaGpXcrFwGRUGNJFmqHnDY_rYHrlala3QwRWtGY4K5Ij6dmjBHrwZyUhrFj_plFqiFE2h8QukOUD5GkJegQOyLWMcGjeQQ_26e3nssM1F7uNzH4i4","expires_in":5183999}{ "errorCode": 0, "message": "Empty oauth2_access_token", "requestId": "8UMZSHXY4C", "status": 401, "timestamp": 1436187852689 }
```